# A CREATE script exported by MySQL Workbench has syntax error on another computer

Tags: mysql, syntax, limit, mysql-workbench, procedure

I created a database on my computer, with **MySQL 5.5** and **MySQL Workbench 5.2.34 CE** installed.
Then i want to migrate the database to another computer, which has **MySQL 5.0** installed. (I just need to migrate the schema, data are not needed)

I use the MySQL Workbench's *File -> Export -> Forward Engineer SQL CREATE script* to generate **db.sql** script and copy it to the other computer.

I type *mysql < db.sql* to create the database but only to receive an error.

Error occurs here:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `filedb`.`GetIncompleteFileId` (in latestFileId BIGINT UNSIGNED, in serverBits BIT(32), in fileCount SMALLINT UNSIGNED)

BEGIN
    SELECT `id`, `key`, `length`, `path`
    FROM
    (
        SELECT * FROM `filedb`.`fileInfo` WHERE `id` <= latestFileId
    ) AS TempTable
    WHERE (serverBits & `serverownership` NOT IN (serverBits, 0))
    ORDER BY `id` DESC
    LIMIT fileCount;
END

$$
```

The error is near 'fileCount; END'.
If i remove the *"LIMIT fileCount"*, the error disappears.

Anyone tells me what is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the MySQL 5.0 LIMIT arguments must be nonnegative integer constants, not a variables or procedure parameters. Use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) to avoid this error.

From the MySQL 5.0 documentation -

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be non-negative integer constants (except when using
>   prepared statements).

From the MySQL 5.5 documentation -

> The LIMIT clause can be used to constrain the number of rows returned
>   by the SELECT statement. LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments,
>   which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these
>   exceptions:
>
> Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
>
> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables as of MySQL 5.5.6.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I've found another post in MySQL's forum which states the same. Now I need to either choose a workaround or update all MySQL on these computers to 5.5.