# Can't Create Stored Procedure in MySQL 5.0. Don't know what's wrong

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, rank

Below is my code to create an SP that will retrieve a list of high scores from a table.  MySQL keeps telling me that it can't create the stored procedure and to check my syntax even though i can run the query fine on the table with out the stored procedure.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated

```
USE `froggame`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `sp_GetHighScores`;
DELIMITER $$
USE `froggame`$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `froggame`.`sp_GetHighScores` (
IN p_StartFrom     INT)
BEGIN
SELECT
    h.PlayerName,
    h.Score,
    h.Accuracy,
    h.TimePlayed,
     @rownum := @rownum + 1 as Rank
FROM
    HighScores h
    JOIN
        (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
ORDER BY
    h.Score DESC
LIMIT 50 OFFSET p_StartFrom;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Thanks,

Dave

Comment: I think it has something to do with the keyword 'LIMIT'

Comment: Bug is decribed, here http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=11918

Comment: Take a look at this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135133/a-create-script-exported-by-mysql-workbench-has-syntax-error-on-another-computer/11135342#11135342

Comment: Sorry I never got back ya, I ended up using a different method but all these answers helped point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just copied your SQL and it works for me in Mysql 5.5. What errors mysql has been reported?
(I'm using HeidiSQL 7 for test)